# how to make my JTable refresh after adding a new row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

After I add a new row to a `JTable`. The information wrote goes to the txt file, but my `JTable` doesn't shows the last raw. But if I close the program, and run it again, the information it's in the table. So, is there a way to refresh the data in the `JTable` without closing the application and running it again?

```
String[] columns = {"nume", "compozitie", "indicatii", "contraindicatii", "administrare", "pret", "compensabil", "stoc"};

Object[][] data = null;
try {
    File file = new File("medicamente.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    data = new Object[100][];
    String line;
    int numLines = 0;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        data[numLines] = line.split(",");
        numLines++;
    }

    fileReader.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns) {
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        Class returnValue;
        if ((column >= 0) && (column < getColumnCount())) {
            returnValue = getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        } else {
            returnValue = Object.class;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
};

JTable table = new JTable(model) {
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
};

final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));
mainPanel.add(scrollPane);
scrollPane.setBounds(0, 240, 995, 510);

final JTextField filterText = new JTextField(null);
mainPanel.add(filterText);
filterText.setBounds(0, 750, 850, 25);

JButton button = new JButton("Filter");
mainPanel.add(button);
button.setBounds(850, 750, 150, 25);
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String text = filterText.getText();
        if (text.length() == 0) {
            sorter.setRowFilter(null);
            //   model.fireTableDataChanged();                       

        } else {
            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like a classic case for `validate()` or `revalidate()` on the component that has the table on it.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to add rows. I don't see it in your code.

Comment: when i press a button, a new window opens and i enter the data needed for the new row. it's a separate JPanel in a subclass. the is no direct conection between the twopannels

Answer (score 3):

It looks like what you think is that when the file updates, so should the `JTable`. It doesn't work like that.  What you need to do is add a row to the `TableModel`. A disadvantage in your case is this

```
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(   data, columns)
```

You're using the `TableModel` interface, which has very limited methods you can use. Instead do this

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(   data, columns)
```

Then you can use one of these methods from `DefaultTableModel`

- [`public void addRow(Object[] rowData)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) - Adds a row to the end of the model. The new row will contain null values unless rowData is specified. Notification of the row being added will be generated.
- [`public void addRow(Vector rowData)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) - Adds a row to the end of the model. The new row will contain null values unless rowData is specified. Notification of the row being added will be generated.

So when you want to add a row, you can gather your data into an array, `addRow(..)` then the table will get automatically update for you.

```
Object[] row = { data1, data2, data2, data4, data5 };
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
model.addRow(row);
```

Also it looks to me like your `JTable` is locally scoped. You may want to give it a global, class member scope, so you can access it from where ever you need to.

Answer (score 1):

you must add your data to the model of jtable and then add the model to jtable and it will be refreshed , but before that you have to define a model .

Comment: i will clarify to you the steps to do , when you add a row to jtable in reality you are adding  row to your txt file , so you have to get data from you file and then add it to object with two dimensions so you have to repeat your first code to get the news object[][] after that you add your object to the model with this method :
model.setDataVector(data, header);
then add your model to your jtable as bellow
jtable1.setmodel(model);
it's so easy just follow the logic of code

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
private void resetListData() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 
{
 Connection cne = null;
  try {


    // create connection in this line as per your database like I used sqlite. so my connection string is as follow
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    cne = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:table.sqlite");
    cne.setAutoCommit(false);

    PreparedStatement psd = (PreparedStatement) cne.prepareStatement("Select * from table");                
    psd.execute();
    ResultSet r = psd.getResultSet();
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = r.getMetaData();
    int count = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    String[] meta = new String[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {
        String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i + 1);
        meta[i] = name;
        //System.out.println(name);
    }
    model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{}, new String[]{"name", "address"});
    jTable1.setModel(model);
    while (r.next()) 
    {
        Object[] row = new Object[count];
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; ++i) 
        {
            row[i - 1] = r.getString(i);  // Or even rs.getObject() 
        }
        model.addRow(row);
    }
    cne.close();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
}
}
```

create connection and query as per your need.. my code add one row at the end of Jtable. My code directly working with your database..

Thanks..

Comment: Don't think I'm picking on you, because I'm not. But the question has nothing to do with database. Data is being read from a file. It helps to read questions (and not just the title) before answer. I make that mistake sometimes myself :)

Comment: @peeskillet: no man its really okay but I give my answer before he posted the code.. that's why I added line `My code directly working with your database..` after showing his code..

Comment: this DefaultTableModel + JTable isn't added to container, then never will be visible, OP wants to reload model (create a new model and to add to JTable) to already visible JTable

Comment: @peeskillet: you can see by this link check http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c381a250-0cf0-478f-8253-4fcda1d2e46d/view-source

Answer (score 0):

by the way why you're using TableRowSorter in your code , why you don't use just the jtable and defaultmodel directly

Comment: because i use a filter function

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem and the solution was to call

```
model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

right after adding the new row to the model.

My issue was the following: I had a table on which I allowed sorting. Without clicking the column headers so that the rows would sort accordingly, I was able to add data to the model and see the changes in the table by calling `table.revalidate();` However, if, at any time, I clicked the column headers, any row added afterwards wouldn't be shown, although the model data was updating properly. By only calling `model.fireTableDataChanged();` after adding the data to the model, it works as a charm.